# Nested android application won't launch

Tags: java, android, exception

I have an Android application with a main activity called GameOfLifeGameActivity in a package called edu.brandeis.gameoflife.

It extends a class in a different package (and different Eclipse project) called GameActivity in a package called edu.brandeis.minigamee. I am having trouble getting it to launch.

I think it has to do with the cross-package and cross project reference. It never gets to the onCreate. Instead, it looks like during startup of the app, I get this fatal exception (see below.)

What might that mean and how to fix it?

```
07-08 13:50:19.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(347): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-08 13:50:19.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(347): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{edu.brandeis.gameoflife/edu.brandeis.gameoflife.GameOfLifeGameActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: edu.brandeis.gameoflife.GameOfLifeGameActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/edu.brandeis.gameoflife-1.apk]
07-08 13:50:19.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(347):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
07-08 13:50:19.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(347):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
07-08 13:50:19.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(347):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
07-08 13:50:19.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(347):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
07-08 13:50:19.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(347):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-08 13:50:19.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(347):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-08 13:50:19.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(347):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-08 13:50:19.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(347):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-08 13:50:19.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(347):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-08 13:50:19.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(347):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-08 13:50:19.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(347):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-08 13:50:19.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(347):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-08 13:50:19.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(347): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: edu.brandeis.gameoflife.GameOfLifeGameActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/edu.brandeis.gameoflife-1.apk]
07-08 13:50:19.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(347):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
07-08 13:50:19.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(347):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
07-08 13:50:19.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(347):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
07-08 13:50:19.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(347):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
07-08 13:50:19.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(347):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
07-08 13:50:19.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(347):     ... 11 more
07-08 13:50:19.980: WARN/ActivityManager(60):   Force finishing activity edu.brandeis.gameoflife/.GameOfLifeGameActivity
07-08 13:50:20.491: WARN/ActivityManager(60): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{4052d618 edu.brandeis.gameoflife/.GameOfLifeGameActivity}
07-08 13:50:30.691: WARN/ActivityManager(60): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{4052d618 edu.brandeis.gameoflife/.GameOfLifeGameActivity}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never seen a project that uses a class from a separate project. I don't know for a fact that this won't work, I've just never seen it. So I would suggest copying your edu.brandeis.minigamee package into the same project that contains GameOfLifeGameActivity.

Comment: That worked. And a further improvement is to create a Jar for the referenced Eclipse project and copy just the jar over to the referencing Eclipse project. Only weakness with that scheme is that as I am still writing the library, every time I change the library and it gets rebuilt I have to manually recreate the jar and put it in the client project. Thanks!